# VSCode MetaJump for UI?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I wanted to ask, is it possible to create extension like [MetaJump](https://github.com/metaseed/metaGo/blob/master/src/metaJump/README.md#metajump) but for VSCode UI? Because lets be honest, the shortcut system for the UI is terrible and it is not possible to use VSCode completely mouseless.

I would imagine a prefix that shows anchors on each and every clickable element in the UI and then waits for the input and sends click command to the specified place. I have never created extension for VSCode so far, and I don't want to invest time learning just to find out that this is impossible.

So I seek confirmation from the experienced ones? Is it possible to create something like I just wrote about? (If yes, then I will have motivation to create one.)

I have found that the extensions have no access to UIs DOM structure? Is that the showstopper? Because that would explain why no one created such extension yet ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of metajump. I have similar idea like you before, but the design of the vscode prevents the extension to get the dom of vscode, because the extension runs in seperate Process, and the extension's capacity is confined to use exposed api to communicate with vscode. to my capbility extent, although metago extention's goal is to be the coolest mouseless extention in vscode, but I can only provide what it has now.